# Generic Extension - Service does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong here.

I'm trying to implement a generic extension method for a service in .Net Core.

Here's my interface -

```
public interface IContactService : IAddable<Contact>
{
    Task<List<Contact>> GetAll();
}
```

My model -

```
public partial class Contact : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And the interface for the model -

```
public interface IBaseEntity { }
```

Then I have my generic extension -

```
public interface IAddable<T>
{
    AppContext Context { get; }
}

public static class IAddableExentions
{
    public static async Task<T> Add<T>(this IAddable<T> addable, T entity) where T : class, IBaseEntity
    {
        await addable.Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        await addable.Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return entity;
    }
}
```

And my service -

```
public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    public AppContext Context;

    public ContactService(AppContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Contact>> GetAll()
    {
        var contacts = await Context
            .Contacts
            .ToListAsync();

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler is complaining that -

> 'ContactService' does not implement interface member
>   'IAddable.Context'

And when I try to call `service.Add(contact)` I'm getting -

> IContactService does not contain a definition for Add and no
>   accessable extension method accepting the first argument of type
>   IContactService could be found.

I've got this working in another project but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's not working here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `Context` as a field of `ContactService`,

```
public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    public AppContext Context; //<-- field

//...
```

but the `IAddable<T>` interface

```
public interface IAddable<T>
{
    AppContext Context { get; }
}
```

of which `IContactService` is derived from, dictates that it (`Context`) should be a property:

```
public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    public AppContext Context { get; }

//...
```